# Upper bound for a norm like quantity

Tags: calculus, probability, functional-analysis

Let $s>1$. Let $p$ and $q$ be probability distributions on a finite set $\mathcal{X}$. Let $f$ be a continuous probability density on an interval $(a,b)$. I am looking for an upper-bound for the quantity $\sum_x p(x) (f(t)q(x))^{s-1}$ independent of $f(t)$. If we apply Holder's inequality appropriately, then we get
$$\sum_x p(x) (f(t)q(x))^{s-1}\le \|p\|\cdot f(t)^{s-1}\cdot \|q\|^{s-1},$$ where $\|\cdot\|$ denotes $s$-norm. As a result the $f$ on both sides get cancelled. This is why I am looking for an upper-bound independent of $f$. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If you're looking for an upper-bound for a fixed $t$, then wouldn't there be no upper bound? For any $M<\infty$ and $t\in(a,b)$, we can define a continuous random variable on $(a,b)$ such that $f(t) > M$. Then $\sum_x p(x)(f(t)q(x))^{s-1} \geq M^{s-1}\max_x p(x)(q(x))^{s-1}$ which can grow arbitrarily large with $M$. It may be possible to get something if you are willing to look at $L^p((a,b))$ bounds of $t \mapsto \sum_x p(x)(f(t)q(x))^{s-1}$.

Comment: @forgottenarrow: Yes you are right. I too realized it later. Maybe what I want is not true.